# concatenate binary files with length headers in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, concatenation, protocols

Is there any simple and easy way to concatenate lots of binary files together?
Currently, my best bet is iterating over them with python, opening each one, computing the length, creating the header, prepending it and so forth.
Is there an easy way to do it with shell?

The results needs to be:

```
<file0's length>[file0's binary data] <file1's length>[file1's binary data] ...
```

Comment: I assume the file lengths should be stored as 4 or 8 bytes, not in decimal.

Comment: @lhf Yeah, 4 bytes is enough, they are tiny files. The files are already "compressed" so I just wish to pack them together in a way my code could unpack them later. My code already unpacks a file of chunks prepended with a 4 byte representation of their length.

Comment: Could you precise the context ? Does the result need to be exactly in the format your specify ? I would suggest using just `tar`, but it does not give the exact same output.

Comment: @Guillaume Was thinking more in the lines of magically convert the size from ls into 4 bytes and then streaming the contents of the file into a single file with a for loop. Easy to do in Python but it's curious if it's simple to do with bash or something. My code is already expecting this "protocol".